# unique_together does not replace primary key

Tags: django, postgresql

In my Django app, I want to insert a record with a composite primary key. Apparently this should be possible by making use of "unique_together".  I'm quite sure this code was working in the past, but for some reason it does not seem to be working now. This code used to run on a Linux VM, and now I'm hosting it in Google App Engine. However I don't see how this can be the cause for this error.

```
class TermsAndConditionsDocument(models.Model):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=_("Organization"))
    language = models.CharField(_('Language'),choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, max_length=5, help_text=_("The language of the content."))
    content = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('organization', 'language')
```

The error:

```
IntegrityError at /transactions/settings/terms_and_conditions

null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, nl-BE, <p>B</p>, 10).
```

According to what I've read, using "unique_together" should cause Django to not need or include an ID as primary key. I checked the database, and the ID field DOES exist. I do not understand where the database constraint and the ID field are still coming from?

Comment: [Django doesn't support composite primary keys](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/MultipleColumnPrimaryKeys). Your model above always had a hidden, autogenerated `id` primary key.

Comment: No, unique_together and PK are not mutually exclusive. unique_together has no effect on PK. And composite PK looks like a great idea only in theory. In practice it is hard to find what issues it eliminates and what benefits it brings.

Comment: Because of the comments here I suspect that the id field might have lost its autoincrement functionality (probably implemented as a postgresql sequence) when I moved the database. I will look into this.

Comment: I used `unique_together` too and I had to change `null=True` by `default=' '` in order to get `unique_together` took into account. It seems to be the same issue there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, as pointed out in the comments, a primary key "id" field is always added, even if you don't need it. It's supposed to get out of your way, so you don't even notice its existence. In my case, it required me to give it a value when I created a new record, which is not how things are supposed to work.

A while back I migrated this database from one Postgres database to another Postgres database. I used an SQL dump and load method for this. Some sequences seem to have been lost during that migration.

Because there are no sequences, some fields now lacked autoincrement capabilities, explaining the IntegrityError on insertion.

In order to fix this, I did the following:

1) Export the current data:

```
manage.py dumpdata > data.json
```

2) Drop your database and create a new empty one.

3) Run database migrations:

```
manage.py migrate
```

4) Load the data again, excluding some default data already recreated by Django.

```
manage.py loaddata --exclude auth.permission --exclude contenttypes data.json
```

This procedure seems to have recreated the sequences while also keeping the data.

Answer (score -1):

The unique_together only creates a DB constraint (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#unique-together).

You could create a custom primary key with the option `primary_key` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.primary_key but you could only do that for one field.

But I suggest to just keep the auto increment id field, this works better with Django.

For the error are you saving a model? or doing a raw import?

Comment: It says right in the documentation you referenced that you can only use primary_key=True on 1 field. I agree with everything else.

Comment: I am saving a model.

Comment: @Deepstop my bad overlooked that.

Comment: @Thomas strange do you set the id field yourself?

Comment: No I do not. It was not needed in the past. I suspect the ID field has lost its autoincrement sequence while moving the database, hence the error.